# Checkout Login form Validation Knockout Js Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

i have created a form on checkout step.The form is allow user to navigate on the next step even if email pattern is not valid. How i can make this validation so user can not move until he enter the correct email patteren.

any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot is attached for more clarification.  http://prntscr.com/ng3swn

email form html :

```
<div id="email" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible" class="acc-fields-sec">
<h2 data-bind="i18n: 'Checkout'" data-role="title"></h2>
<div id="checkout-step-title"
     data-role="content">
     <!-- form -->
    <each args="getRegion('login-methods')" render="" />
    <!-- end of form -->
    <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" class="form-next-step" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Checkout'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator,
    customer
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/email'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),
        isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
        //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
        stepCode: 'email',
        //step title value
        stepTitle: 'Email',

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                this.stepCode,
                //step alias
                null,
                this.stepTitle,
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                9
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
```

);

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution for this.

Just added this KO JS to validate the form. Hope this will help to others.

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko',
'uiComponent',
'underscore',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
'mage/translate',
'Magento_Checkout/js/bindings/transitions'
], function ($, ko, Component, _, stepNavigator, customerData, customer, $t) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/email'
    },

    loginFormSelector: 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]',

    isVisible: ko.observable(!customer.isLoggedIn()),

    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        stepNavigator.registerStep('email', null, $t('Email'), this.isVisible, _.bind(this.navigate, this), 5);
        return this;
    },

    navigate: function () {
        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.navigateToNextStep();
        } else {
            this.isVisible(true);
        }
    },

    validateEmail: function () {
        var emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn();

        if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            $(this.loginFormSelector).validation();
            emailValidationResult = Boolean($(this.loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
        }
        return emailValidationResult;
    },

    navigateToNextStep: function () {
        if (this.validateEmail()) {
            stepNavigator.next();
        } else {
            $(this.loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').focus();
        }
    }
});
});
```